# How to handle error rxjs using operator from?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In ngOnChanges I listen Input data to component.

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
    from(this.zuPrimaryData).pipe(
      max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"])
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

First time `this.zuPrimaryData` comes as `null` ir arises error, thus ngChanges works.

How to handle this and dont create stream if null?

This code is not get me data in template:

```
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.zu$ = iif(() => this.data, from(this.data)).pipe(
      max((a, b) => a["n"] - b["n"]),
      map((data) => data)
    );
  }
```

Template is:

```
{{zu$ | async }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a pure RxJS solution, you could use [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) conditional function. Try the following

```js
ngOnChanges(): void {
  iif(() => this.zuPrimaryData, from(this.zuPrimaryData)).pipe(
    max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"])
  ).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Here the observable is created only if the `zuPrimaryData` is defined. If the condition is false, it returns RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant.

From `EMPTY` docs:

> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and
>   immediately emits a complete notification.

<sup>You could also make the condition more explicit for readability: `iif(() => (this.zuPrimaryData && this.zuPrimaryData !== null), from(this.zuPrimaryData))`</sup>

---

### Update: to use `async` pipe

To use the `async` pipe you need to remove the subscription from the controller.

#### Option 1: using `async` pipe

Controller

```js
result$: any;

ngOnChanges(): void {
  this.result$ = iif(() => this.zuPrimaryData, from(this.zuPrimaryData))
    .pipe(max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"]));
}
```

Template

```html
<div>{{ result$ | async }}</div>
```

#### Option 2: using subscription (without `async` pipe)

Controller

```js
result: any;

ngOnChanges(): void {
  iif(() => this.zuPrimaryData, from(this.zuPrimaryData))
    .pipe(max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"]))
    .subscribe(data => this.result = data);
}
```

Template

```html
<div>{{ result }}</div>
```

Comment: It does now work when I subscribe in template: `let result$ = iif(() => this.zuPrimaryData, from(this.zuPrimaryData)).pipe(
    max((a, b) => a["n"] - b["n"])
  );`

{{result$ | async}}

Comment: Loot at my question again

Comment: You should either subscribe in the controller or remove the subscription from the controller and use `async` pipe  in the template. Combining both wouldn't work.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First check if this.zuPrimaryData is there then only create stream.

```
   ngOnChanges(): void {
      if(this.zuPrimaryData) {
        from(this.zuPrimaryData).pipe(
          max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"])
        ).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could I use only rxjs and run stream if not null value?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of filter operator privded by rxjs operators like given below. It will only move ahead if you return true in. this case when value will be null it will cast to false and it will not go ahead.

```
from(this.zuPrimaryData).pipe(
      filter(data=>!!data), 
      max((a, b) => a["nu"] - b["n"])
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Error arises on `from(this.Primary Data)`, not after